# Angular 4, method executes before constructor initialize value

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have Angular 4 application. 
I invoke getCity() method in my service's constructor to initialize cityId property. I use cityId in another method? for example, getData(). When I'm trying to invoke getData() in component I receive error that cityId is undefined. As I think it happens because getCity() doesn't finish it's execution when getData() started to execute.
The both of the methods are use Observables, and return Observable. 
I solved it with getCity().concatMap((id) => getData(...)).

Could You tell me please is it right approach? Maybe there are more correct ways?

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomService {

  cityId: number;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private citiesService: CitiesService) {
    this.getCityId()
  }

  getCityId() {
    return this.citiesService.getCity().subscribe(
      (city) => {
        this.cityId = city['id']
      });
  }

  getData() {
    /* use this.cityId here */
  }
```

Comment: post the code, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on if `getData` is making a service call, can you show what `getData` does?. If getData is making another service call, you can use `switchMap`.
If not, a regular `map` should work for you.

```
    @Injectable()
    export class CustomService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
                private citiesService: CitiesService) {
    }

    getCityId() {
        return this.citiesService.getCity()
    }

    getDataAsynchronous() {
        return this.getCityId()
            .map(city => city.id)
            .switchMap(id => this.service.serviceCall())
    }

    getDataSynchronous() {
        return this.getCityId()
            .map(city => city.id)
            .map(id => processID(id))
    }

    processID(id: string) {
        // do something with id
        return id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke `getData()` method after `getCity()` from service is completed:

```
getCityId() {
  return this.citiesService.getCity().subscribe({
    next: (city) => {
      this.cityId = city['id'];
    }, 
    complete: () => {
      this.getData();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
getCity.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: The OP did a horrible job posting his question so i thought i'd do the same

Comment: seems OP is new here as per his reputation status but you not, so it's your responsibility to provide a quality answer, not like freshers on StackOverflow